# Telegram api getUpdats not ignoring old messages even if offset added

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot

I'm trying to do long polling updates from Telegram, I got the messages from the `getUpdates` api but the messages keep repeating. I have tried to include `offset` parameter with the largest number of `update_id` or +1 of the largest number. None of these works and Telegram keeps giving me the same old updates that I'd like to waive from any new polling messages.
It's the `update_id` not `message_id`. It's a 9 digit number instead of the 1/2/3 from `message_id`. I'm using node.js with `request` module for making requests.

[image]

Sorry for not having the codes as text form, there might be some problem on my pc or browser to browse the site.

Those codes are wrapped within a `setInterval` function and runs once a second.

`requestOptions` content:
`{ method: 'POST', url: 'https://(telegram url)', json: true, data: { offset: ********* } }`
No matter offset being the largest `update_id` or the id + 1, it's not working

I'm not sure what is the problem, is it my bad or Telegram's bug?

Comment: Can you please provide a [mre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @CcmU I'll try, though I'm having problem on browsing this site on my pc